# Как организовать ввод данных через консоль в С#?

Tags: c#

У меня есть переменная `int money = 5000;` и имеется строка

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите любое число: ");
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы со стороны пользователя была ведена любая цифра, и она отнималась от 5000. Например если введено 250, то вычисляется разность

> 5000 - 250 = 4750

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы галку слева от ответа поставьте и тем самым вы закроете вопрос, и поблагодарите человека, который вам помог.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int money = 5000;
    Console.WriteLine("Введите любое число: ");
    string num = Console.ReadLine();
    int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(num);
    int a = money - num1;
    Console.WriteLine("Искомое число: " + a);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Из консоли можно считать только [Строку](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms228362.aspx). Для того, чтобы выполнить арифметическое действие с переменной, её надо привести к типу [`int`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Оперативно :))

Answer (score 2):

Собери свой код из `Console.ReadLine()` и `Int32.Parse()`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!